# jquery getting file value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

How can i check whether the file is selected in file upload or not

Comment: What kind of file? And tell us a bit more about what you are want to do. jQuery has many ways to get files and values.

Comment: Voted to re-open, seems like a perfectly reasonable question that just needs a tiny bit more explanation (IE, does the file exist serverside/client side?)

Comment: I will vote to re-open too once it has actually been improved. Ping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether user upload a file or not you can do

```
var file = $('#FileUploadId').val();
if (file == "") {
alert("Please select a file");
}
```